# Multiple regression, collinearity and hypothesis testing

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, multicollinearity

I would like to fit the data with a linear model for each participant that would look like this:

$$ Y=B_0 + B_1X_1 + (B_2 + B_3X_1)X_2$$

where $B_i$ are the regression coefficients and $X_i$ the regressors.

Depending on participant's particularities, $B_2$ could be positive or negative. But my hypothesis is that $B_3$ should be of the opposite sign than $B_2$ for each participant.

Doing that, by hypothesis $B_3$ and $B_2$ should be correlated. So, two questions:

**1.** Isn't that an issue for the fitting?

**2.** If not, which kind of test should I run to test my hypothesis?

Comment: What do you mean by "fit a linear model for each participant"?  Regression estimates the coefficients for groups of subjects (participants).

Comment: I mean that I would collect about 500 trials for each participant and fit the data for each participant individually in order to find regression estimates for each subject

Comment: Why not collect all data, add a categorical variable `participant` and fit a single model?

Comment: Because actually, the hypothesis that I want to test is the opposite sign between B2 and B3 for each participant (independently of the sign of B2, that could differ between participants)